# $S^1/G$ homeomorphic to $S^1$ when $G$ is a finite group acting freely on $S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite group acting freely on $S^1$. I saw from [here](http://www.math.utah.edu/~keenan/actions.pdf)(proof of proposition 1) that $S^1/G$ homeomorphic to $S^1$. Which theorem is used here? Is there a direct proof of this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to prove this is via the classification of $1$-manifolds.  As JoeJohnson said in a deleted answer, any finite group acting freely on a manifold $M$ gives a cover $M\rightarrow M/G$ where $M/G$ is a topological manifold (without boundary) (and $M/G$ is smooth if $M$ is smooth and the action is by diffeomorphisms).

When $M = S^1$, $M/G$ must be compact since it's the continuous image of $S^1$ under the covering map.  Then, from [the classification of $1$-manifolds](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/1-manifolds), it follows that $M/G$  must be homeomorphic to $S^1$ since it's the only compact $1$-manifold without boundary.

Comment: Thank you! But what do you mean by "the action is by diffeomorphisms"?

Comment: @TiWen:  For each $g\in G$, the map $f_g:M\rightarrow M$ given by $f_g(m) = g\ast m$ is a homeomorphism.  One can ask for every $f_g$ to be a diffeomorphism.  If this happens, the action is said to be by diffeomorphisms.  Another viewpoint:  an action is a map $G\rightarrow Homeo(M)$, where $Homeo(M)$ is the group of homeomorphisms of $M$.  The space $Homeo(M)$ has a subgroup $Diff(M)$, the diffeomorphism of $M$.  One can as the image of $G$ to lie in $Diff(M)$.  Then one says the actions is by diffeomorphisms.